# How to have a dropdown box in a jquery datatable which uses an ajax call to retrieve the data

Tags: jquery, datatables

I want to have a dropdown box in one of the columns of my datatable. Like in [this](https://datatables.net/examples/api/form.html) example. But my table sources it's data through an ajax call which gets the data from the server. This means that I can't just put a  option group inside a td. What is the easiest way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **SOLUTION**

You can use [`columns.defaultContent`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.defaultContent) if content (your dropdown box) doesn't depend on row's data, or [`columns.render`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) for content that depends on row's data.

> **DEMO**

See [Generated content for a column](http://datatables.net/examples/ajax/null_data_source.html) example for demonstration of [`columns.defaultContent`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.defaultContent) option usage.